# Java thread terminates abnormally with an exception with message null.

Tags: java, windows, multithreading

I am trying to execute a multithreaded program, using the Executors of Java. On execution the java thread terminates abnormally. I caught the exception , through try-catch, however, the exception has no message in it (null).

The failure is random, however I "suspect" that the failure is happening after I have made function calls in that thread. I tried to increase the thread stack size to 1024/2048 , but the result remains same.

Can someone please point out to the debugging approach to be adopted here. Since, I do not have the info about the exception I am not able to proceed with it.

I am working in Windows 64-bit environment, with java 1.6

Comment: Please tell us the exception class name (like `NullPointerException`). And the stack trace might be helpful too.

Comment: You are probably encountering a NullPointerException. Can you post a part of your code here??

Comment: You can use this, to get the stack trace:
... catch (Exception e) {e.printStackStrace();}

Comment: I found out later that one of the called routines was failing with NPE, although the thread stack trace did not show that it was NPE, which was killing it. printStackTrace did not work for threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the Executors class to create the thread pool use the method that accepts ThreadFactory; example `ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads, ThreadFactory threadFactory)`.
In your implementation of the ThreadFactory, assign an UncaughtExceptionHandler; example below

```
public final Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
    Thread newThread = threadFactory.newThread(r); // you can use default thread factory
    newThread.setName("threadName");
    newThread.setDaemon(Boolean.TRUE);
    newThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(final Thread t, final Throwable e) {
            // log
        }
    });
    return newThread;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a nice programming practice to follow, especially with the uncaught exceptions in the inner layer subroutines.

Comment: to give your more details, the task that is submitted via ExecutorService gets wrapped into a FutureTask which catches Throwable and makes the exception available via FutureTask#get(); so this practice really makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! Also found out that we can have a timeout too from the same FutureTask. I was looking for this, for long!! Thanks!!

Comment: @SiddharthShankaran maybe then you can accept this answer ;-)